# Difference between two google play services apk

Tags: android, apk, google-play-services

Does anyone know the difference between 150xxx and 170xxx apk for Android 11 or 190xxx and 200xxx apk for android 12? I cant figure it out... They both say that they are for v7&v8 arm but they dont say what is the difference between them..
Basically i want to update the google play services to the latest version on my phone..
The phones normally i think they use the 150 and 190 variant, but i am curious about the 170 and 200 of the apks..
Thanks..

I tried both variants (190 and 200) on my phone (android 12) and didnt see anything going wrong.. Both of the apks worked ok, but the curiosity still remains about the difference between them.. I cant find an answer..

Just to add i am not referring to the screen resolution dpi etc..

Lets take as example the 150400 & 170400 variants and the 190400 & 200400 that are nodpi.. What else changes between them besides the android version and the arch..

Comment: Play services are closed source and additionally obfuscated, so detecting changes isn't that easy and requires reverse engineering skills. So I don't think you will find someone who can answer your question.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer.. I guess you are right.. But the thing is not so much about the changes.. It is more about each variant.. They mention that a variant is for x dpi screen or for x architecture or for x android version.. But i cant figure out what is the difference on the 150&170 and 190&200 variants that seem to be targeting the same thing... The only things that changes are, the filesize, the libraries permissions and features on each variant.. Dont know.. I just wanted to have the latest version.. That usually takes some time to be available through play.. Not to be beta tester.